# fastest way to see if IEnumerable<T> contains item based on criteria

Tags: linq, contains

Sort of a Linq beginners question, but is there a simple **built-in** way to optimize this:

```
bool containsItemWithValue42 = items.Where(i => i.Value == 42).Count() > 0;
```

I would like Linq to stop iterating as soon as it found a match.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) method does exactly that:

```
bool containsItemWithValue42 = items.Any(i => i.Value == 42);
```